# How to write into an Apache Arrow feather file in C++?

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

What is the minimal example of a C++ code that writes data to the [Feather format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/feather.html) that Apache Arrow supports?  The file will be later used to do mmapped reads from Python code.

Assume we have an instance of [`arrow::Table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/table.html#_CPPv4N5arrow5TableE), how to write the contents of it into a feather file?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is not at all documented in the [Arrow documentation site](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/index.html), so I collected it together from the Arrow source code.  I hope someone can recommend an easier / more official method.

I used [the Arrow example code](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/examples/row_columnar_conversion.html) to generate the `arrow::Table`, and then used the following to write from C++:

```
#include "arrow/io/api.h"
#include "arrow/ipc/feather.h"

// ...
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = //...;
std::shared_ptr<FileOutputStream> file;
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(file, FileOutputStream::Open(filename, /*append=*/true));
ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(arrow::ipc::feather::WriteTable(*table, file.get()));
ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(file->Close());
```

and the following to read from Python.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.feather as feather

with pa.memory_map('myfile.feather', 'r') as stream:
    table = feather.read_feather(stream)
print(table)
```

The Python's code output was:

```
$ python read_feather.py
   id  cost  cost_components
0   1   1.0            [1.0]
1   2   2.0       [1.0, 2.0]
2   3   3.0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: this helped me a lot trying to write a table from C++. Do you have by any chance an example on how to read back the feather file C++? It's really easy from python, as per your example, but I can't find anywhere an example to read it from C++